# How to get duplication on Map with local language and in English language using Leafletjs and OSM

Tags: vue.js, leaflet, openstreetmap

I have created a map in vuejs using leafletjs and Openstreetmap ( using there official site: https://leafletjs.com/),

```
 more code here......
<l-tile-layer
        url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
        attribution='&copy; <a target="_blank" 
        href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>'
></l-tile-layer>
```

But now I want to have both local original language and also English language display on my map same way as we have in ( see image below)

> https://liveuamap.com/

[image]

I have google and checked many tutorials but cannot find exactly what I am looking for.
How can I achieve this for my map using vuejs.
And secondly I also need to turn off the English language, so if user want to see only local language or want to see the English language, so there can be options to do it.
Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks in Advance !

Answer (score 1):

You would either need to change to a vector tile provider that offers different language options (e.g. MapTiler does) or if you want to use Leaflet and raster tiles - use a tile provider that offers English labels. E.g. MapTiles API offers either local or English labels with raster tiles worldwide (but not both combined).

E.g. this one (you'll need an API key) would show English labels:

```
<l-tile-layer
    url="https://maptiles.p.rapidapi.com/en/map/v1/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?rapidapi-key=XXXXXX"
    attribution='&copy; data <a target="_blank" 
    href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>, &copy; tiles <a target="_blank" href="https://www.maptilesapi.com">MapTiles API</a>'></l-tile-layer>
```

Edit: found a map layer with English/local labels mix: The Thunderforest map tiles show both the English and local label similar to your liveuamap example. You would need an API key as well.

Code example:

```
<l-tile-layer
    url="https://tile.thunderforest.com/neighbourhood/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?apikey==XXXXXX"
    attribution='&copy; data <a target="_blank" 
    href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>, &copy; tiles <a target="_blank" href="https://www.thunderforest.com">Thunderforest</a>'></l-tile-layer>
```

Regarding the toggle: with raster tiles this would only be possible by having a map layer switcher (called layers control in Leaflet, see here: https://leafletjs.com/SlavaUkraini/examples/layers-control/ ). E.g. one layer with standard OpenStreetMap tiles, the other with e.g. the MapTiles API English tiles and one with the Thunderforest tiles.

Comment: Thanks for your response, haven't tried yet but will soon :)